# jquery unexpected token on radio click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here's my code

```
// when the DOM is ready
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // 'click' because IE likes to choke on 'change'
    $('input[name=passedparameter]').click(function(e) {
        // prevent normal, boring, tedious form submission
        e.preventDefault();
        // send it to the server out-of-band with XHR
        $.post('http://localhost/topostthepost.php', function() {
            data: $(this).val(),
            success: function(resp) {
                if(resp == '1') {
                    alert('Saved successfully');
                } else {
                    alert('Oops, something went wrong!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

im new to jQuery, even in javascript,
but as far as i thought, this was logically possible and right code,

-when i open the response page, (`http://localhost/topostthepost.php`), i went good,
-im using php framework, so i need to post "`http://localhost/`" so i got the right url,
-when i run the page, it wont do a thing, i inspect element (Chrome) it, and it warns `unexpected token`

what do i missed? is jquery/javascript deny `http://` in the `$.post`?

PS:Code credit to [karim79](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626807/2187893)

Comment: have you imported jquery?

Comment: `input[name=passedparameter]` should be `input[name="passedparameter"]`

Comment: Is the unexpected token on the line with the "$"?

Comment: have you included the jquery lib ?

Comment: Does it work if you change the "$" to the word "jQuery"?

Comment: @slash197: No, you don't need the quotes if the attribute value only has a subset of characters.

Comment: @BeNdErR: That would be a *different* error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very subtle:

```
// when the DOM is ready
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // 'click' because IE likes to choke on 'change'
    $('input[name=passedparameter]').click(function(e) {
        // prevent normal, boring, tedious form submission
        e.preventDefault();
        // send it to the server out-of-band with XHR
        $.post('http://localhost/topostthepost.php', function() {
        // Problem is here ========================= ^^^^^^^^^^   <<==========
            data: $(this).val(),
            success: function(resp) {
                if(resp == '1') {
                    alert('Saved successfully');
                } else {
                    alert('Oops, something went wrong!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It shouldn't have `function` there, what you're passing is an object. With `function`, the `:` after `success` becomes a syntax error. (The one after `data` is fine because it looks like a label, but then the comma at the end of the line means we're still within an expression, so the `:` after `success` is the culprit.)

But note that that's not how you call `$.post`, it's similar to how you call `$.ajax`. Here's the updated code without a syntax error and switching to `$.ajax`:

```
// when the DOM is ready
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // 'click' because IE likes to choke on 'change'
    $('input[name=passedparameter]').click(function(e) {
        // prevent normal, boring, tedious form submission
        e.preventDefault();
        // send it to the server out-of-band with XHR
        $.ajax({
            url:     'http://localhost/topostthepost.php',
            type:    'POST',
            data:    $(this).val(),
            success: function(resp) {
                if(resp == '1') {
                    alert('Saved successfully');
                } else {
                    alert('Oops, something went wrong!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However, this bit still looks dodgy:

```
data:    $(this).val(),
```

That means you're passing a *string* into the call. If you give a string, it must *already* be properly encoded. So you must either encode it, or pass an object instead so jQuery can encode it for you:

```
data:    {someParameterName: $(this).val()},
```

...where `someParameterName` is what the server will look for in the form data server-side. That's passing an *object* as the `data` parameter to the call. The object has (in this case) just one property, which I've called `someParameterName` above, with the value from `$(this).val()`.

When you send a `POST` into the system, by default it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, which fundamentally consists of names and values — for instance, form field names and the values of those fields. So in the above, I'm sending a field *name* `someParameterName` and the value from `$(this).val()`. Because we're passing `data` as an object, jQuery will handle encoding the names and values for us.

On the server receiving the `POST`, it would look in the post data, using the field name `someParameterName`) to get the value.

Obviously you'd use a more appropriate parameter name than `someParameterName`.

Here's a hypothetical example giving more than one field:

```
data: {
    firstName: $("input[name=firstName]").val(),
    lastName:  $("input[name=lastName]").val()
}
```

There I'm posting two fields (parameters), with the names `firstName` and `lastName`.

Comment: +1 A very thorough answer. `data:    $(this).val()` is definitely not right, not only the encoding but the value will become the HTTP request body with no identifier so the server side will have to read the raw POST data to get it, instead of `$_POST['someParameterName']`.

Comment: @MrCode: Well, that depends -- if the value has a `=` in it... ;-)

Comment: this went `unexpected identifier`, on `data:    $(this).val(),`, can you give reference or explain about `someParameterName:` means?

Comment: @HenryJahja: Sorry, I was missing a comma after `type: 'POST'`. I've added it. I've also added more about the `data: $(this).val()` bit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder mybad for not look after that comma either !. thank you very much! it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think error is because of this line `$.post('http://localhost/topostthepost.php', function() {`

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // 'click' because IE likes to choke on 'change'
    $('input[name=passedparameter]').click(function(e) {
        // prevent normal, boring, tedious form submission
        e.preventDefault();
        // send it to the server out-of-band with XHR
        $.post('http://localhost/topostthepost.php', {data: $(this).val()}, function(resp) {
            if (resp == '1') {
                alert('Saved successfully');
            } else {
                alert('Oops, something went wrong!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Jinx! ......... ;-) Except that's not how you call `post` (it's how you call `ajax`)